# Spacing between letters of multi-letter identifier changes randomly

Tags: fonts, math-mode, spacing, italic

I use multi-letter identifiers in my thesis, for which I wrote macros, for example:

```
\newcommand{\spec}{\mathit{Spec}}
```

In a text, I always refer to these identifiers as:

```
some words $\spec$ even more words
```

In some texts however, latex changes the spacing between the letters:
The output looks like

"some words S p e c even more words"

instead of the usual

"some words Spec even more words".

How do I prevent latex from adding spaces and always output the latter?

EDIT: Here is a minimal example.
The spacing on page one is weird, the spacing on page two is correct.
Any ideas?

```
\documentclass[%
twoside=true,
paper=a4,
BCOR=5mm,
headinclude=true,
footinclude=true,
fontsize=10pt,
titlepage=true,
abstract=off,
parskip=half-,
headsepline,
footsepline,
cleardoublepage=empty,
open=right,
numbers=noenddot,
fleqn,
index=totoc,
listof=totoc,
american
]{scrreprt}

\PassOptionsToPackage{%
drafting,           % timestamp on every page
pdfspacing         % makes use of pdftex’ letter spacing capabilities
}{classicthesis}

\PassOptionsToPackage{american}{babel}
\usepackage{babel}


\usepackage{classicthesis}
\newcommand{\spec}{\mathit{Spec}}
\newcommand{\sd}{\mathit{stopdead}}
\newcommand{\bb}{\mathit{b}}


\begin{document}

\chapter{$\bb$-conformance}

Some words $\spec$ some more words.
This is very weird $\sd$-semantics behavior and $\sd$-semantics looks really ugly.

\newpage

Some words $\spec$ some more words.
This is normal $\sd$-semantics behavior.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Minimal example please, ie something we can copy and run on our machines.

Comment: are you sure you always include the backslash?  if you happen to input `$Spec$` instead of `$\Spec$`, the individual letters would be "spaced out" since they are being treated as individual variables, not as a word.  without an actual example to test, it's impossible to be sure.

Comment: Thanks, but I always use the backslash. I'm going to build a minimal example (which is kinda difficult because I use a lot of packages).

Comment: If I remove the `pdfspacing` option, I get what you would like to have (don't ask me why, though)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems to be a bug with `classicthesis`; it is triggered by `\b` in the chapter title, when `\mathit` is used.

This doesn't seem to happen when you use `\textit` instead of `\mathit`.

```
\documentclass[%
twoside=true,
paper=a4,
BCOR=5mm,
headinclude=true,
footinclude=true,
fontsize=10pt,
titlepage=true,
abstract=off,
%parskip=half-,% <--- PLEASE, DON'T USE THIS
headsepline,
footsepline,
cleardoublepage=empty,
open=right,
numbers=noenddot,
fleqn,
index=totoc,
listof=totoc,
american
]{scrreprt}


\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[
  drafting,
  pdfspacing,
]{classicthesis}

\newcommand{\spec}{\textit{Spec}}
\newcommand{\sd}{\textit{stopdead}}
\newcommand{\bb}{\textit{b}}


\begin{document}

\chapter{\texorpdfstring{$\bb$}{b}-conformance}

Some words $\spec$ some more words.
This is very weird $\sd$-semantics behavior and
$\sd$-semantics looks really ugly.

Some words $\spec$ some more words.
This is normal $\sd$-semantics behavior.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note also that `b` is not uppercased in the title; the `\texorpdfstring` is used to avoid a spurious warning.

Please, don't use `parskip-`.

Comment: Thanks! \textit instead of \mathit seems to work, although I have no idea why.
The lowercase b in the title is there on purpose, because it is a mathematical variable.

Can you explain why I shouldn't use parskip-?

Comment: I've no idea, either: I'll try and investigate. You shouldn't use `parsnip-` because using it is a clear sign of bad typography.

Comment: @Rich It seems to be the fault of `classicthesis` and the bug is triggered by the `\mathit` in the chapter title.

Comment: I think it's a bug in `microtype`, actually. The same happens with `\documentclass{article} \usepackage{microtype}
\begin{document} \textls[200]{$\mathit{b}$-conformance} Some words $\mathit{spec}$ some more words. \end{document}`. The problem is that during math font setup, LaTeX sets `\globaldefs1`, with the result that the letterspaced font instance will leak out. I'll have to see what I can do about it.

Comment: The following should help (after loading `classicthesis`): `\def\MT@set@lsfont{\MT@exp@two@c\let\font@name\MT@lsfont\global\let\glb@currsize\@empty}` (which, alas, will slow down `microtype`, again).

Comment: Your fix (I put it in the next line after
    \usepackage{classicthesis}
) does not work for me.